# Working on a Dynamic table to add and delete rows in Vuejs framework, Below is my table

Tags: javascript, html, validation, vue.js, select

```
<div class="card-headerfrm" style="margin:0 0px 15px -20px; overflow: auto">
<form method="post" id="form2" class="form-horizontal" v-on:submit.prevent="submitForm">
<table class="table-hover tbl datatables" style="width:100%;">
  <head>
    <tr class="text-primary table-bordered">
    <td class="text-center tableheader"><b>Name</b></td>
    <td class="text-center tableheader"><b>Email</b></td>
    <td class="text-center tableheader"><b>Contact No</b></td>
    <td class="text-center tableheader"><b>Type</b></td>
    <td class="text-center tableheader"><b>Person Type</b></td>
    <td class="text-center tableheader"><b>Remove</b></td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody v-for="(input,index) in inputs" :key="index">
  {{input}}
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b-form-fieldset>
        <b-input-group>
          <b-form-input 
             type="text" 
             placeholder="Enter Registered Name" 
             v-model="input.name"
             :name="'name'+index"
             v-validate="{required:true, max: 30, regex: /^[a-z\d\-_\s]+$/i}" 
             v-bind:class="{'form-control': true, 'error': errors.has('name'+index) }">
          </b-form-input>
        </b-input-group>
        <span v-show="errors.has('name'+index)" class="text-danger">{{ errors.first('name'+index) }}</span>
      </b-form-fieldset>
  </td>
    <td>
      <b-form-fieldset>
        <b-input-group>
          <b-form-input 
             type="text" 
             placeholder="Enter Email" 
             v-model="input.email"
             :name="'email'+index"
           v-validate="{required:true, max: 30, regex: /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/}"
             v-bind:class="{'form-control': true, 'error': errors.has('email'+index) }">
            </b-form-input>
        </b-input-group>
        <span v-show="errors.has('email'+index)" class="text-danger">{{ errors.first('email'+index) }}</span>
      </b-form-fieldset>
  </td>
    <td>
      <b-form-fieldset>
        <b-input-group>
          <b-form-input 
             type="text" 
             placeholder="Enter Contact No"
             v-model="input.contactno"
             :name="'contactno'+index"
             v-validate="{required:true, regex: /^(0|[+91]{3})?[7-9][0-9]{9}$/}" 
             v-bind:class="{'form-control': true, 'error': errors.has('contactno'+index) }">
           </b-form-input>
        </b-input-group>
        <span v-show="errors.has('contactno'+index)" class="text-danger">{{ errors.first('contactno'+index) }}</span>
      </b-form-fieldset>
  </td>
  <td>
    <b-form-fieldset>
      <b-input-group>
        <basic-select 
             :options="typeOption"
             :selected-option="selectedType.objectArray[index]" 
             v-model="input.type"
             :name="'type'+index"
             placeholder="Select Type"
             @select="typeFunc"
             v-validate="{required:true}"
             v-bind:class="{'form-control': true, 'error': errors.has('type'+index)}">
        </basic-select>
      </b-input-group>
    </b-form-fieldset>
  </td>
  <td>
    <b-form-fieldset>
      <b-input-group>
        <basic-select 
             :options="personTypeOption"
             :selected-option="selectedPersonType.objectArray[index]" 
             v-model="input.persontype"
             :name="'persontype'+index"
             placeholder="Person Type"
             @select="personTypeFunc"
             v-validate="{required: true}"
             v-bind:class="{'form-control': true, 'error': errors.has('persontype'+index)}">
         </basic-select>
      </b-input-group>
    </b-form-fieldset>
  </td>
  <td class="text-center"><h4><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" @click="removeRow(index)"></i></h4></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Submit

```
    export default {
    name:'',
    components:{VueElementLoading, BasicSelect},
    data(){
    return {
    selectedType:{ objectArray:[] },
    selectedPersonType:{ objectArray:[] },
    typeOption:[{
    value:1,
    text: "Operation"
    },
    {
    value:2,
    text: "Technology"
    },
    {
    value:3,
    text: "Finance And Legal"
    }],
    personTypeOption:[{
    value: 1,
    text: "Xpressbees"
    },
    {
    value: 2,
    text: "Client"
    }],
    inputs:[],
    }
    },
    created: function(){

    },
   mounted(){

   },
   methods:{
     typeFunc(cls){
       this.selectedType.objectArray.push(cls)
     },
     personTypeFunc(cls){
       this.selectedPersonType.object.push(cls)
     },
     openList(){
       if(this.inputs.length === 0){
         this.showList = true
         this.inputs.push({
           name:'',
           email:'',
           contactno:'',
           type:'',
           persontype:''
         });
       }else {
           this.addInput()
       }
     },
     addInput() {
       this.inputs.push({
         name:'',
         email:'',
         contactno:'',
         type:'',
         persontype:''
       });
       },
     AddNewFunction() {
       this.showList = true
       this.inputs = [];
       if (this.inputs.length == 0) {
         this.addInput();
       }
     },
     onSubmit: function(event){
       this.$validator.validateAll()
       .then(res =>{
         if (res) {
         this.showList = true
         this.getAllClientsDetails()
       }else {
         return false
       }
       }).catch(err =>{
         console.log("Error Details", err);
       })
     },
     submitForm: function(event){
       this.$validator.validateAll()
       .then(res =>{

         if (res) {
           this.SaveSpockDetails()
         }else {
           return false
         }
       }).catch(err =>{
         console.log("Error Details", err);
       })
     }
        }
      }
```

So I am writing a code in javascript framework (Vuejs) for dynamically add and delete rows from a table. And I want the user to first fill the first opened row(line) and then click on the Add button, then that row goes for a validation check. And if the validation results are true then open second-row otherwise show an error. And to validate field I am using `this.$validator.validateAll()` function which validates all fields on the submit button.
I have 3 text fields and 2 select fields in the table,
1) Name
2) Email
3) Contact Number
4) Type (select)
5) Person Type (select)

in which 3 input-text fields are working fine but in the select field I am getting a validation error 
It shows validation error, even after selected any of the values from the dropdown box.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this code it might help

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $field_Values_array = $_POST['field_name'];
    $pass_array = $_POST['class'];

    $sg = "";

    $len1 = count($field_Values_array);

    $x=0;
    while($x<$len1){
        $sg = $sg."Book - ".$field_Values_array[$x]." Set - ".implode(", ",$pass_array[$x])."<br>";
        $x++;
    }

    echo $sg;

    print '<pre>' ; print_r($field_Values_array); print '</pre>';
    print '<pre>' ; print_r($pass_array); print '</pre>';
}

?>


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<?php 
$index = 0;
?>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-6khuMg9gaYr5AxOqhkVIODVIvm9ynTT5J4V1cfthmT+emCG6yVmEZsRHdxlotUnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var index = parseInt('<?php echo $index; ?>');
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTML = '<div><select id="a1" name="field_name[indexed]"><option selected disabled>     </option><option>महात्मा गांधी</option><option>बिल्ली</option><option>घोड़ा</option><option>नारियल</option><option>केरल</option><option>चावल</option><option>महाराष्ट्र</option><option>महाबली</option><option>रमेश</option><option>दिल्ली</option><option>किताब </option><option>कछुआ</option></select> <input type="checkbox" name="class[indexed][]" value="A" />A <input type="checkbox" name="class[indexed][]" value="B" />B <input type="checkbox" name="class[indexed][]" value="C" />C <input type="checkbox" name="class[indexed][]" value="1" />1 <input type="checkbox" name="class[indexed][]" value="2" />2 <input type="checkbox" name="class[indexed][]" value="3" />3 <input type="checkbox" name="class[indexed][]" value="4" />4 <input type="checkbox" name="class[indexed][]" value="5" />5 <input type="checkbox" name="class[indexed][]" value="6" />6 <input type="checkbox" name="class[indexed][]" value="7" />7 <input type="checkbox" name="class[indexed][]" value="8" />8 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button"><img src="remove.png"/></a></div>'; //New input field html 
    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1

    //Once add button is clicked
    $(addButton).click(function(){
        //Check maximum number of input fields
        index++;

        newHTML = fieldHTML.replace(/indexed/g, index);



        if(x < maxField){ 
            x++; //Increment field counter
            $(wrapper).append(newHTML); //Add field html
        }
    });

    //Once remove button is clicked
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
    });
});

window.onload = function(e){ 
   $('#a1').append("<option selected disabled></option><option>महात्मा गांधी</option><option>बिल्ली</option><option>घोड़ा</option><option>नारियल</option><option>केरल</option><option>चावल</option><option>महाराष्ट्र</option><option>महाबली</option><option>रमेश</option><option>दिल्ली</option><option>किताब </option><option>कछुआ</option>");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <div class="field_wrapper">
            <div>
                <input type="text" readonly value="Book Name"/>
                <input type="text" readonly value="Book Set"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <select id="a1" name="field_name[<?php echo $index; ?>]"></select>
                <!--<input type="text" name="field_name[<?php echo $index; ?>]" value=""/>-->
                <input type="checkbox" name="class[<?php echo $index; ?>][]" value="A" />A
                <input type="checkbox" name="class[<?php echo $index; ?>][]" value="B" />B
                <input type="checkbox" name="class[<?php echo $index; ?>][]" value="C" />C
                <input type="checkbox" name="class[<?php echo $index; ?>][]" value="1" />1
                <input type="checkbox" name="class[<?php echo $index; ?>][]" value="2" />2
                <input type="checkbox" name="class[<?php echo $index; ?>][]" value="3" />3
                <input type="checkbox" name="class[<?php echo $index; ?>][]" value="4" />4
                <input type="checkbox" name="class[<?php echo $index; ?>][]" value="5" />5
                <input type="checkbox" name="class[<?php echo $index; ?>][]" value="6" />6
                <input type="checkbox" name="class[<?php echo $index; ?>][]" value="7" />7
                <input type="checkbox" name="class[<?php echo $index; ?>][]" value="8" />8
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"><img src="add.png"/></a>
            </div>
        </div><br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

At least you've got 2 keys with the same name in `data()` function. Remove first
Or juts edit your `data` func to:

```
 data(){
    return {
     selectedTypes:[]
    }
 }
```

And change all callings to this

Comment: pay your attention please on styleguide https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Multi-attribute-elements-strongly-recommended
It's strongly recommended to put not more than 1 attr per line. First time it may be strange and uncomfortable, but it's really better, your code will be more readable)